# Initializing IsolatedState results in IllegalStateException

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am trying to use `IsolatedState` from `Stately` in my project. E.g. I have a view model, containing some data structure to display. It is initialized with that data structure instance and then I'm trying to create an `IsolatedState` to be able to apply user actions and bg actions to mutate the same instance from different threads.

```kotlin
class ViewModel() {

    constructor(data: SomeData) : this() {
        println("Hey: ${data.isFrozen}")
        println(1)
        isolatedData = IsolateState { data }
        println(2)
    }

    lateinit private var isolatedData: IsolateState<SomeData>

}
```

The output is

```
Hey: false
1
```

And then the exception `kotlin.IllegalStateException: Mutable state shouldn't be frozen` is raised. So it seems that `data` is not frozen before initializing `IsolatedState`. Is something wrong in the way I am initializing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is something wrong in the way I am initializing it?

Yes. The constructor for `IsolateState` takes a producer lambda. That lambda should return some data that is mutable (ie. not frozen). The lambda itself runs in a different thread that is controlled by the runtime that manages `IsolateState`. That lambda needs to be frozen to be run on that thread, which freezes `data`.

For this to work, it would need to look something more like the following:

```kotlin
    constructor(id: Int) : this() {
        isolatedData = IsolateState { SomeData(id) }
    }
```

The lambda basically needs to create the mutable class instance. You can't pass mutable data into an instance of `IsolateState`. The producer lambda needs to create it.